# Cannot type after Gnome login since last update

Tags: 11.04, keyboard

last time I let my Ubuntu 11.04 to upgrade all its packages, I think a new kernel was also downloaded. Since then keyboard stopped working so that I can press Enter button on the login screen, but after I get the desktop ready I cannot type. The kernel version is 2.6.38 but if I boot with 2.6.35 nothing changes. I can start Ubuntu in recovery mode, keyboard is working there, but I don't know what to do there.

When I looked around the settings on a certain menu point (Input settings or kind of) I got an error message that IBus daemon is not started. I was asked if I'd like to start it, but after starting nothing got better.

Do you have any idea how could I get my keyboard working again?

UPDATE: after a recovery mode package update keyboard is working, but I have to press each button for about 1 second to see the letter on the screen, fast typing is impossible. Key combinations, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> are not working at all.

Comment: Find out, whether the upgrade went all right. Login at a text console (if GUI is not working) and look what aptitude says.

Comment: Could you tell me the exact command you think of..?

Comment: Try `apt-get -f install`. [Old article](https://www.linux.com/archive/feature/48910)

Comment: `apt-get -f install` told all OK.

Comment: see the updated question..

Comment: rerun `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` - any more errors seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, somehow "Slow keys" got enabled, I don't know how. After disabling it keyboard is OK. What a terrible feature. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/1924